# Backbone / Underscore Filter multi-dimensional collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am currently working on a Backbone app and am using backbone-forms to generate some of the forms used within the app. I have a form with two select boxes that pull data in from collectons via my API.

The second of these select boxes is dependent on the value of the first (category to product relation). However a product can belong to multiple categories so the standard `_.where` in underscore wont do.

This is what the JSON roughly looks like for a category:

```
{id: 1, name: "Category 1"}
```

And then this is the JSON for product:

```
{id: 1, name: "Product 1", categories: [{cat_id: 1},{cat_id: 2}]}
```

I need some way to filter on the id when the first select value is chosen.

Comment: Have you thought about indexing it the other way?  `{category:1, products: []}`

Comment: I had thought about it however the same issue presents it's self, the issue is drilling down to the data regardless of the collection it is stored in. As the _.filter and _.where functions are top level as far as i am aware.

Answer (score 0):

```
var categoryId = 1; //your selected category id

var filteredProducts = _.filter(products, function (product) {
   return !!_.findWhere(product.categories, {id: categoryId });
});
```

Worst case efficiency - O(n^2)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JrUd7/)

Comment: This seems to be returning every product regardless of the _.findWhere statement.

Comment: Try it with the change.  I removed the undefined check and used a `!!` casting.  I also provided a fiddle to demonstrate it works (this time).

Comment: When i pass my collection into the filter my product variable is undefined? Do i need to modify the collection before passing it in as in your fiddle your just passing in JSON data

Comment: In my fiddle, I'm passing in an array of objects (not to be confused with JSON which is a string format).  I'm not sure if you do need to modify your collection, can you link a fiddle that you've tried to change?

Answer (score 0):

You could polish your data a little bit so that it's easier to drill down:

```
_.each(products, function(product) {
    product.categoryIds = _.pluck(product.categories, "cat_id");
});
```

Now you can simply search through it for a certain `cat_id` with:

```
var result = _.filter(products, function(product) {
    return _.contains(product.categoryIds, cat_id);
});
```

Or if you want to use a more memory but faster access (useful when multiple selects are made):

```
var cats = _.reduce(categories, function(map, category) {
    map[category.id] = category;
    category.products = [];
    return map;
}, {});
_.each(products, function(product) {
    _.each(product.categories, function(category) {
        cats[category.cat_id].products.push(product);
    });
});
```

and then

```
var result = cats[cat_id].products;
```